# Why can I not select camera trackers in the graph view of the Movie Clip Editor?

Tags: interface, tracking

I am currently following video 07_Feature_Detection.m4v from Sebastien Konig's Match Track Blend DVD. The selection of camera tracking markers in the graph view (in order to detect and remove erratic markers) seems unreliable.

When I create markers by Feature Detection, all the markers are selectable in the graph view. But when I create and track my own markers (which the tutorial suggests is the best option) I find that I cannot right-click-and-select any marker but the one which is already selected in the editing clip preview.

I'm a little confused and annoyed. =)

[My current .blend and my lower-res Sofia footage](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n3e18kdxmy466er/avIqjHfONV)

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I tried creating and tracking some markers in a new blendfile, everything worked as expected. Perhaps a (very strange) bug?

Comment: 1) To check - you tried my .blend with the footage and experienced the same behavior on the graph view that I did? 2) Did anything about the markers I placed seem strange to you? Not expecting you to say 'yes' to this, but I'm trying to figure out if it's something I did. Finally, if this IS a bug, is there an approved way to submit this to the Blender team? And thanks for the comment...!

Comment: **1** Yes, I did try your file and I experienced the same behavior as described. **2** I didn't see anything odd. **3** See [here](http://www.blender.org/development/report-a-bug/) and [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports). Bugs should be reported to the [tracker](https://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=browse&group_id=9&atid=498).