# How can I avoid this camera tracking error? "Some data failed to reconstruct (see console for details)"

Tags: camera, tracking

I'm currently following Sebastien Konig's Match Track Blend DVD and have encountered a problem where despite matching camera type, lens type and trying to solve for distortion, I'm getting the following console messages when I try to Solve Camera Motion:

```
bpy.ops.clip.solve_camera()
Some data failed to reconstruct (see console for details)
```

And I'm getting an average Solve Error of 0.9561, where I'm used to getting .4 and below. So what's going on?

The related files can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n3e18kdxmy466er/avIqjHfONV).

This may be related to another question I've asked on the site - [Why can I not select camera trackers in the graph view of the Movie Clip Editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/why-can-i-not-select-camera-trackers-in-the-graph-view-of-the-movie-clip-editor)
I figured that the issues were different enough that I should give them different questions.

Many thanks to everyone who built and everyone who visits this site. StackExchange/Answers style-sites are very useful to me and I appreciate any time spent trying to answer the questions people ask here. (Thus ends that digression!)

Comment: What does it say in the [console](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Console_window) when this occurs?

Comment: I have been able to reproduce this, but I haven't found any consistent reasons for this happening.. The only thing that happens every time is problematic tracks will not display any average error. I can get rid of this by [cleaning bad trackers](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Motion_Tracking#Cleanup_Panel) and making sure there are a good number of good trackers, but I don't know what actually causes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:
Here are a few measures to fix this issue:
Take good footage that isn't to shaky or blurred.
Double check that all of your tracks are accurate.
Add more accurate tracks.
Delete a track, then solve camera motion if it didn't help, chose a different track and then and repeat.
make sure that not all your tracks are on one single plane in space (eg. on a wall)
If all fails, then your shot is simply to difficult to solve.