# What values do the --verbose and --debug-value options accept?

Tags: command-line

Running blender with either

```
blender --verbose
```

or

```
blender --debug-value
```

returns `Error: you must specify a verbosity level.`

The [wiki page about command line options](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Command_Line#Debug_Options%3a) does not specify what these options do or what values they accept.

What are some values that these options accept, and what do they do?

Comment: Did you try --verbose 1 or 2 (or any integer)?

Comment: @RóbertLászlóPáli yes, but I couldn't see any differences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both these arguments are mainly for developers.

- `--verbose` is currently only used by `libmv` (camera tracking), however we will likely use in the future to control other output.
- `--debug-value` is mainly for developers to test alternative behavior, from Python you can access it from `bpy.app.debug_value` from C/C++ you can access it from `G.debug_value` (with `BKE_global.h` include).

For example `--debug-value 2` makes the manipulator rotation handles draw differently.

For verbose logging with camera tracking use `--verbose 2`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. it just so happens that I wanted verbosity for camera tracking. (trying to reproduce [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2709/how-can-i-avoid-this-camera-tracking-error-some-data-failed-to-reconstruct-se))

Comment: How about adding this to the Blender documentation? This is the about third time I stumbled over this, wasted my time trying to get more info and the verbose value gets totally ignored, it does nothing. Please specify that it is NOT a general verbose value (as the man page or help suggest), but a specific one.