# Suppresing render console output

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, rendering

Is there way to suppress (and possibly process) console output when rendering from script?
I have batch script to set up model material etc. via CLI and I want to show overall progress of the job (for example `"Image1.png done"`, `"Image2.png done"` etc...).

I want to get rid of these lines:

```
Fra:5 Mem:115.16M (0.00M, Peak 213.60M) | Time:17:15.52 | Remaining:07:30.02 | Mem:26.82M, Peak:26.82M | Scene, Render-Alpha | Path Tracing Tile 45/64, Sample 1079/2000
```

to make output more readable.
Is there any way to do it?

It would be nice to display rendering progress without flooding console (for example as `"50% done"`, but this would be just finishing touch :D) - I would be glad to just remove console output completely.

I tried redirecting output via:

```
sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
```

and some other examples using contextlib.contextmanager but neither did work (console was still flooded with progress messages)

I would like to do it directly in python - I am on Windows so using grep awk or other tools is complicated. Plus it would be nice to control script output from one place.

Comment: there is a a command line argument --verbose it could help you but I can't find any documented list of values, see also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/what-values-do-the-verbose-and-debug-value-options-accept

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28615/silent-command-line-rendering

Comment: @zeffii: Didn't found that one :/. But this no solution would work, as I need to print some other text. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DominiqueParisot your comment is actually a great answer! Just convert it to an answer please :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the message you want to get ride (*Fra:5...*) is printed directly on *stdout* by a *fprintf* function (`source/blender/render/intern/source/pipeline.c`). It's not printed by a specific function which has a hook with python... And I don't think the embedded Python engine has the power to act on the pipe between the console and Blender. I think the only way to do what you want is to write an external launcher script to filter Blender *stdout*. As you don't want to use external tools like *awk*, you can use the Blender python engine which is in the blender directory.