# Motion tracking is oriented incorrectly; no depth

Tags: tracking

I took a quick video on my iPhone 4, and tracked it in Blender. It appears to have tracked quite well. Note that I have some tracks in the foreground and some in the background:

[image: Example of tracks in movie clip viewer]

However, after solving, Blender seems to think that all the tracks are basically planar, at a roughly fixed distance from the camera:

[image]

I used the tripod solve mode, because the camera isn't moving (just panning/rolling) in the shot, as suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8969/372). Is this correct?

I did select the "iPhone 4" preset, but I didn't change any of the other settings.

What can I do to get the scene to be tracked correctly?

---

- Video file: [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1aoga1bdu8f1cu/2014-11-22%2008.55.58.mov?dl=0).
- Blend file (not packed; video not included): [PasteAll link](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33009).

Comment: As for the orientation. Try using the orientation tools to determine floor and origin.

Comment: @cegaton Hmm…I hadn't noticed that, but [it looks like you're right](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pQkCl.png). Do you know any workarounds? (I tried without tripod solve and it's really jumpy.)

Comment: @cegaton I tried setting Origin and X–Y axes, but it didn't turn out quite right (at an odd angle, and I'm going to be doing simulations, so that won't work). I also tried to use Floor, but the floor was placed perpendicular to how it should be, because the tracks aren't correctly solved.

Comment: @cegaton Thanks very much! It didn't occur to me that you could reposition the camera even though it has the *Camera Solver* constraint. So the key, then, is that the Camera Solver constraint is relative, not absolute? (If you post an answer I'll accept it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the camera is not moving (you're not walking or otherwise displacing the camera to have some parallax) the only way to solve the shot is using tripod solve. Normal solve will only give you errors.

It's very hard however to accurately get depth on a tripod solve.

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Motion_Tracker):

> tripod can be used for footage where the camera does not move and only
>   rotates. Such footage can't be tracked with a generic solver approach,
>   and it's impossible to determine the actual feature points in space
>   due to a lack of information. So this solver will solve only the
>   relative camera rotation and then reproject the feature points into a
>   sphere, with the same distance between feature and camera for all
>   feature points.

Once the scene is solved you might not get the right orientation using the default tools (like floor, wall or origin) but you can set manually by selecting the camera in the 3D viewport and rotating it to make the plane and cube match the orientation of the real images (remember to set the original footage as background image). All the trackers are parented to the camera, so they will follow it as you move it along.

What you want to get is something like this:

sample file [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33017)
[image]