# Tracking markers are clustered together and too close to camera

Tags: tracking

I tracked a shot (most of the markers in the screenshot are red because no marker stays in frame throughout the shot, so lots of markers pop in and lots of markers stop tracking but it still gives enough to solve) and the way I tracked it, the markers should be spaced out in 3D space. However, they are clustered together and too close to the camera. This might be caused by the strange width and height of the camera, but I'm not sure (the video I'm tracking is vertical)
Here's what it looks like when it's being tracked:
[image]

And here's what it looks like in the 3D view:
[image]

How do I fix this/why is it happening?

Comment: Did you set the scale at the time of solving the scene? Have you tried scaling the camera? What kind of solution did you choose (default or tripod)? Is the camera just panning or is the camera also moving? (Read item 5 on [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)). Please use the [edit] link under your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project.

Comment: Possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/motion-tracking-is-oriented-incorrectly-no-depth/19148#19148

Answer (score -1):

In the orientation panel place a larger distance value and press the apply scale button