# How to track such "flat" videos? Flat: Mostly moving camera on a paper plane or so

Tags: tracking

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-oSc_KRHnw
I mean the video in the video. The spider creature and the buildings etc.

Would I solve this live-action plate as a Tripod? There is no Parallax information, right? How should I track this? What special settings do I use here?

Those are all the same questions. They all lead to one question. How to track such videos without parallax information?

Live action plate: The video behind the CGI.
Video: Multiple frames played behind each other.
CGI = Computer Generated Imagery

Comment: Could you please update your question to have better grammar? It is hard to understand your question.

Comment: Which part, specifically, of the linked video are you wishing to track?

Comment: I edited it.. I hope that is clear now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Motion tracking is oriented incorrectly; no depth](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/motion-tracking-is-oriented-incorrectly-no-depth)

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332 #5