# Syncing a Blender camera tracking scene to an Fspy camera match

Tags: camera, tracking

I've been having issues orientating a tracking scene--
For a recent project, I started by doing a camera match on the first frame in Fspy, which produced an amazing result, as evidence by the sample geometry I added as a test:

[image]

However, after taking the rest of the footage through blender's camera tracking process, I'm finding it impossible to line up with the above Fspy import. 
The Fspy import gave the scene a Field of View of **48.16**, while the camera tracking seems to be spitting out a Field of View of around **13.5** . Is there someway I can alter the camera track to generate the 48.16 Field of view? Is there a better way to orient the scene without needing to go through Fspy? Happy to provide the Blend file/Fspy export if needed. [image: Camera track points and solve].
[image: After clicking set up tracking scene]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/motion-tracking-is-oriented-incorrectly-no-depth/19148#19148 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/problem-with-camera-orientation-in-motion-tracking/58120#58120

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your tracked scene it seems to me that you don't have enough parallax to solve the scene using the default settings. There hardly any movement in those trackers, or not enough for blender to determine real 3d information.

Such static scenes should be solved as "tripod". But before, solving the scene use the field of view (or lens and sensor combination) you got from fSpy.

Once the scene is solved as tripod you can manually align it with the existing geometry. Note that tripod solve will not give you accurate 3d but just a visual reference.

Read: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking) and [Correct tracked camera orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/correct-tracked-camera-orientation/10708#10708)

Alternatively, given that the camera is not really moving, consider doing a stabilized version of the shot, and use that with the camera from fspy.