# Cannot get my camera to solve correctly during a motion track

Tags: tracking, compositing-nodes

I am trying to track the included scene to remove the black wall and replace it with something else. Problem is, I can't for the life of me figure out how to track this properly and get it right. I have over 8 track points, with a very low solve error, but the plane won't correctly sit where it needs to. Can somebody help me get it right?
[image]

Also, this is my first question on SE. Let me know if I can do anything to better answer my question :)

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible to do anything with the provided file. The video does not get packed with the blender file. It looks to me that you don't have any parallax information. If the camera is only panning, but not displacing you can't really determine 3D information.

Comment: You need to solve as " Tripod". Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/motion-tracking-is-oriented-incorrectly-no-depth and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/problem-with-camera-orientation-in-motion-tracking/58120#58120

Comment: Read the detailed post on tracking here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332