# 2.74 Camera Solve failing despite having 8 consistent tracks and matching keyframes

Tags: video, tracking

I'm sure this must be something I have just overlooked or misunderstood, but I cannot for figure out why I can't solve camera motion in this situation.

I have 8 tracked points, with seemingly very smooth motion, yet when attempting to solve camera motion it refuses giving the "At least 8 common tracks are needed on both key-frames for reconstruction". My keyframes are at frames 0 and 67, the same as was set for solving. Yet I still get nothing each time.

[Here](https://gfycat.com/ThunderousHorribleFlee) is a short clip of the situation for additional context.

You can see that the 8 points track from 0 to 67 then stop, yet that range for solving does not work.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Most of your trackers are in a single plane, there is hardly any movement describing any parallax, which means there is not much for blender to reconstruct the geometry with.

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8969/1853 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27630/how-to-pick-good-keyframes-for-motion-tracking