# How to make good camera tracking markers

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, tracking

I am going to be making a scene where I will be using camera tracking for the first time and I was wondering how to make good markers for good scene tracking... the scene is going to consist of just white drywall with a ball smashing through it from the inside of the drywall into view... I will be using cell fracture and bullet constraints for the scene... If there would be any other good tips for me to know, it would be great if you could comment it... But I need to know how to make good markers for camera tracking... Thank you very much!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27630/how-to-pick-good-keyframes-for-motion-tracking

Comment: Could I maybe tape some black dots on the wall? Would that help?

Comment: anything that is different than the color of the wall.

Comment: some other info here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8969/1853

Comment: Ok thank you so much sir... Very helpful indeed!

Comment: https://vonlitch.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/tracking-markers/ and https://www.google.com/search?q=tracking+markers&safe=off&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CB4QsARqFQoTCOGHveqP38cCFcqigAod7m4N8g&biw=1920&bih=1019

Comment: related: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5541/what-kind-of-camera-do-i-need-to-record-a-moving-object-in-order-to-do-motion-tr

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about blender.

Answer (score 3):

For proper tracking you need to find features that are distinct and recognizable form frame to frame. Usually points with contrast or a color that is different than the background.

A white wall with no such features will not give you much information for proper reconstruction so you will need to add something that the trackers can follow.

When you shoot the scene you can add pieces of color tape or things you can stick to the wall that will provide a good reference (like putty, or color plastiline dots). Depending on the size of the frame usually pieces of tape cut in triangles work well. Sometimes a piece of tape in the form of an X will work.
Others use color stickers or pieces of paper with black and white patterns.

When you make a shot meant for motion tracking try to avoid sudden moves that might distort the image or create motion blur. Or that will make the trackers less readable.

Keep in mind that for a proper reconstruction you need at least 8 tracking points. But don't limit yourself to only that number, have more just in case the tracking process fails.