# How to set the correct keyframes on a motion tracked scene?

Tags: tracking

I recorded this clip at school and I'm trying to track it, but the Solve error is usually around 3 and I think its the "Solve Keyframes"

[image]

I think im getting those two keyframes wrong, so could someone provide me with advice here? Or maybe suggest where the keyframes should be? Thanks.
Also my camera is a Canon Vixia HF M40

The Source Video: https://youtu.be/J5woVOZIhvs

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27630/how-to-pick-good-keyframes-for-motion-tracking/27656#27656

Comment: Solve error of 3 is too high, try to get it to be unde 1, even better all the way to 0.3