# How to figure out which parts of a track don't have enough markers

Tags: tracking

I'm tracking a shot where none of the markers stay in frame the whole time, so I make up for the markers lost by adding new ones. I make sure there's at least 9 active markers every frame, but it still tells me I need 8 common tracks on each keyframe. How can I figure out which parts of my shot don't have enough markers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pick good keyframes for motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27630/how-to-pick-good-keyframes-for-motion-tracking)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the markers to stay in the frame for the duration of the shot, but you do need to have at least 8 successful trackers for a section from which blender can solve the scene.

The range of frames used for solving can be set in the solve section Keyframe A and B

[image]

If you can't decide which range of frames is best, you can let Blender decide for you by enabling the Keyframe option on the solve tab.

**Please read through the following link: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42329/1853)**