# Motion tracking with large sweeping camera moves

Tags: tracking

Hi I wish to motion track a scene that involves large sweeps which means the end frame contains none of the markers placed in the first frame. I'm not sure how to have adaptive markers or markers that are not in the first frame which are included in the solve/bundle? I'm coming from boujou where it updates new trackers if old ones are not on screen.

Comment: You don't need trackers that are present from the beginning to the end of the shot. You do need however at least 8 good tracking points at some section of the shot that will give a decent camera solution. Blender will still try to solve the whole shot. Read the following related links: [How to pick good keyframes for motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27630/how-to-pick-good-keyframes-for-motion-tracking/27656#27656)