# Solve Error High

Tags: tracking

I don't know why the solve error is high? It should have been an easy tracking. Footage have well contrasting markers. Can anyone please help me understand why this is happening and how can I get more accurate Tracking?[Here's my blend test file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q5TNKkrMd7knEoiXke3lFoCHi7A7Y3ub)

Comment: Read also: [how can I get better results when doing 
 camera motion tracking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332)

Comment: and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8934/some-data-failed-to-reconstruct-motion-tracking

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to do the following:

- Delete sliding tracks on the tracking plane (I've removed 2 or 3, don't remember exactly)
- Delete all tracks on the ground floor
- Set keyframes (parallax should be as much as possible)

[image: Solve error 0.87]